# How to create tags in Resource Management of Python azure SDK?

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk-python

I am working with Python azure 2.0.0rc2 SDK and looking to create few tags. Can anyone suggest me the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag operations are included in **azure.mgmt.resource.resources.operations** module. You can use **create_or_update(tag_name, custom_headers={}, raw=False, **operation_config)** to create tags. Check **[azure.mgmt.resource.resources.operations.TagsOperations](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/azure.mgmt.resource.resources.operations.html/#azure.mgmt.resource.resources.operations.TagsOperations)** for details.

Comment: I am trying following code to create/update tags:
`credentials = UserPassCredentials(username=username, password=password)
        resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials=credentials)
        tag_operations = TagOperations(client=resource_client)
        tag_operations.create_or_update_value(tag_name='key_1', tag_value='val_1')`

But getting error like:

`if self.client.credentials.subscription_id is not None:
AttributeError: 'UserPassCredentials' object has no attribute 'subscription_id'`

How to solve it?

Comment: @chandanmishra I have replied in the new thread you created, please check.

Comment: I have got the solution, the problem was related to package installation.
To get these properties we need to install package by
`pip install --pre azure` command on centos, but i used `pip install azure`

Comment: @chandanmishra Or you can specify the version directly, `pip install azure==2.0.0rc2`.